# Zend PHPunit with oracle database

Tags: php, oracle, zend-framework, phpunit

I am getting 'Oracle unknown exception' when trying to retrieve data from oracle db using phpunit but the development code works without issues only when i try from phpunit it is throwing exception.

Comment: show the code so we can see what you are on

Comment: You should really be mocking the database response rather than making your unit tests dependent on it